# Determine the area delimited by a graph

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, area

Given a connected graph as a set of edges and the 2D coordinates of their vertices, how it is calculated the area delimited by the external lines of the graph (a sort of "envelope" of the graph). Note that in the (most probably irregular) shape obtained, not all the edges correspond with edges in the original graph, and some new vertices might be determined at the cross-points of some edges.

Comment: this seems like the problem of finding the 'convex hull' of a set of points. having a graph structure over the points should probably not make any difference?

Comment: It seems to be similar, but it would not work for some cases, like this one: https://ibb.co/JxtVVx2

Comment: ok, perhaps that should be in the question then. I know nothing about them, but it seems like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape might be what you need although there should be a simpler algorithm for examples like the one you show, I feel

Answer (score 1):

[Pick's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) may help you.

If a polygon has integer coordinates (lattice points) for all of its vertices then
the area of the polygon is $$i+\frac{1}{2}p−1,$$ where $i$ is the number of lattice points inside the polygon and $p$ is the number of lattice points on the perimeter of the polygon.

Comment: The points that puzzle me here are 1) how to determine what points are "interior" to the polygon, and 2) how to determine what points are in the "perimeter". I mean, for any possible graph with integer coordinates for its vertices.

Comment: @nightcod3r Actually, there are several algorithms to check whether a given point in the plane lies inside, outside, or on the boundary of a polygon. You can start from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon